# Difficulty with showing JSONP results in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain, jsonp

This is driving me crazy. I wrote a php api file and stored it on my server. When I run the url directly the JSON results are perfectly echoed to the screen, with no problem. However, when I attempt to access the results from another domain (e.g. Cross domain) I can not get the values to show. The screen is still blank. I hope this is making sense. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my javascript call below. This is really becoming a royal pain.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The code below:

Note: 
//Example of what the JSON results would look like 
    { 
    "name": "John Doe", 
    "url": "http://www.adomain.com", 
    "created": "A DATE HERE" 
    }

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "      
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<html>
<head>
<title>API JSON Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript"    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var timeService = "http://api.MYDOMAIN.com/api.php?  
key=abc&num=1&format=json&callback=?";

$.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {
$('showdata').html("<p>ulore="+data.name+" url="+data.url+" created="+data.created+"   
</p>");
});
});
</script>
<div id="showdata"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate any response that could help. This is very strange to me. On my remote server, all is fine. I've successfully encoded it in JSONP and have valid result. However, each and every time I attempt to access the JSONP results - either from the same domain or via cross-domain, the screen is blank. I've tried 1 million different things and have been at this for a couple of days now. I have been reading forums etc and no one else seem to have this kind of problem, not to the extent to which I'm having it. Note that below is what the JSONP looks like:

```
?({"posts":[{"post":{"name":"Mike     
Jones","url":"http:\/\/aweburl.com","timestamp":"2011-12-08 09:48:04"}}]});
```

For the life of me I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `showdata` will match `<showdata>` you want `#showdata`

Comment: Oh and I forgot to include what the JSON looks like. ?({"post":{"ulore":"k6ih7a","url":"http:\/\/somedomain.com\/index.html","created":"2011-07-13 05:31:34"}});

Answer (score 0):

You should probably listen to the HTTP requests send by your browser using a developer plugin or e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com). Often you see HTTP response codes that might tell you more that just a blank screen :) Could be an authorization issue for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in append HTML to the result . 

It should be like this :

```
$.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {
$('#showdata').html("<p>ulore="+data.name+" url="+data.url+" created="+data.created+"   
</p>");
```

try with this syntax..

Thanks

Comment: Hey guys, first and foremost THANKS. You guys are the best. Special thanks to Abhishek Bhalani. I missed that the one thing the whole time. Now things are almost there. Got just one more slight issue. The results appear on the screen but they read as....    ulore=undefined url=undefined created=undefined     So the values of data.ulore, for example, are not being displayed. Is there any particular reason why... Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: One other point. If I alert the results of the JSONP, e.g. alert(data.post) it will show object Object  Everything else shows up as undefined.

Comment: try with print "console.write(data);" , "console.write(data.post);" or can you give me webservice method which you used for calling for response. so It will very clear.

Comment: OR you can try with "data.post.url" I think every properties set within post (Root) element..

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.  I found the problem. If you guys can remember the JSONP results I posted... Well my javascript code was flawed. After a bit of checking I changed to the following....

My variables were incorrect. So I changed, for example, from data.url TO date.post.url and it works like a charm. I have learned alot these past couple of days. Thanks again for all your help. :)

```
$.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {  
  $('#showdata').html("<p>ulore="+data.post.ulore+" url="+data.post.url+
  "created="+data.post.created+"</p>");
});
```